# Disable next/prev at the start/end of the select list

Tags: jquery-ui

I want to be able to disable the previous and next buttons on page load.  Then when I select the first option to disable the previous button and when I select the last option to disable the next button.  When an option between the first and last is selected; both the next and previous buttons should be enabled.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });
```

```
$('.dropdown').change(function() {
    if (($('.dropdown').val() == 0) || ($('.dropdown').val() ==8)) {
      $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });
    } else {
      $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });
    }
});
```

$(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });

`$('.dropdown').change(function() {
    if ($('.dropdown').val() < 2) {
      $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });
    } else {
      $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: false });
    }
});`

It works in my code when I make a selection from the dropdown list, but when I, for example, choose option 2 and click button next to last option it not work. [My demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Godfather/49zdR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your buttons are not triggering a change event in the drop down (which is where you are setting the disabled/enabled status of the buttons).

I have modified your JavaScript so that the Next and Previous buttons trigger the 'change' event for the dropdown; and have slightly modified the code in the 'change' event to account for the behaviors you are trying to create.

You can play with it in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49zdR/13/)

The code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });

    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').val() == 0) {
            //If nothing is selected; only previous button is disabled
            $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });
        } else if ($('.dropdown').val() == 1) {
            //If the first option is selected; enabled the next button
            $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });
            $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });            
        } else if ($('.dropdown').val() == 8) {
            //If the last option is selected disable the next button
            $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true }); 
        } else {
            //Anywhere else we enable both buttons
            $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });
            $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: false });
        }
    });

    $(".prevbutton").button({ disabled: true });        
});

$("#next").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mylist > option:selected').next('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
      $('#mylist > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').next('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
      //Trigger change to modify the status of the drop down/buttons
      $('.dropdown').trigger('change');      
  }
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  var nextElement = $('#mylist > option:selected').prev('option');
  if (nextElement.length > 0) {
      $('#mylist > option:selected').removeAttr('selected').prev('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
      //trigger change; to modify the status of the drop down/buttons
      $('.dropdown').trigger('change');        
  }  
});
```